# Save student data in dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm working on a simple project to save student data in dictionary but when I enter more data using the while loop, the last data entered only is saved.**What do I do to save all entered data?**

> This function is for saving data in dictionary with three parameters
>   (student_name as **key**,student_id and student_gpa as the **values** which is
>   stored in dictionary).

```
def student_info(student_name,student_id,student_gpa):
   student_dic = dict()
   student_dic[student_name] = [student_id,student_gpa]
   return student_dic
```

> This is the rest of the code to take the data from the user and save it in the dictionary through the **student_info function.**

```
while True:
    s = input("Enter 'n' if you want to add a new student,enter 'any key 'if you want to finish: "
    if s == 'n':
        name = input("Student name: ")
        ID = input("Student ID: ")
        gpa = input("Student GPA: ")
        print(student_info(name,ID,gpa))
    else:
        break
```

> Inputs

```
Student name:Micheal
Student ID:12345
Student GPA:3.5
---------------------
Student name:John
Student ID:56789
Student GPA:4
```

> **Expected output**

```
{'Micheal':['12345,'3.5'],'John':['56789','4']}
```

> But this is the output

```
{'John':['56789','4']}
```

Comment: You're creating a new dictionary every time you call `student_info`. Outside your while loop, create a variable for your dictionary, then pass that in to `student_info`. You're not overwriting the old info, you're just not storing it in the same variable.

Comment: try dict update,in place of assigning data.

Comment: Thank you so much
The problem has been solved :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def student_info(student_name,student_id,student_gpa,student_dic ):
   student_dic[student_name] = [student_id,student_gpa]
   return student_dic
sd = dict()

while True:

    s = input("Enter 'n' if you want to add a new student,enter 'any key 'if you want to finish: ")
    if s == 'n':
        name = input("Student name: ")
        ID = input("Student ID: ")
        gpa = input("Student GPA: ")
        print(student_info(name,ID,gpa,sd))
    else:
        break
```

In your case Your function all time creates new object of dictionary. But for expected output you needs only one object of dictionary. And It update Data if key is already exists. Because Key always unique. It gives output

```
Enter 'n' if you want to add a new student,enter 'any key 'if you want to finish: n
Student name: q
Student ID: w
Student GPA: e
{'q': ['w', 'e']}
Enter 'n' if you want to add a new student,enter 'any key 'if you want to finish: n
Student name: w
Student ID: e
Student GPA: r
{'q': ['w', 'e'], 'w': ['e', 'r']}
Enter 'n' if you want to add a new student,enter 'any key 'if you want to finish: n
Student name: q
Student ID: w
Student GPA: e
{'q': ['w', 'e'], 'w': ['e', 'r']}
Enter 'n' if you want to add a new student,enter 'any key 'if you want to finish: n
Student name: ee
Student ID: ee
Student GPA: e
{'q': ['w', 'e'], 'w': ['e', 'r'], 'ee': ['ee', 'e']}
```

Comment: Thank you very much